# How can I send data to an API via the internet securely?

Tags: security, encryption, data-transfer

i'm going to use JAVA to create a system, and in our system we will use an API. the API is going to be accessed via the internet as it always is. my question here is that how can i secure their connection to prevent any snooping around, i know that the data will be safe in the API but it could be prone to danger during transmission. could this be network security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define "security" better. There are several concerns usually related to API security and handling one is different. For example common APIs need to deal with network traffic security (i.e. encryption, verification etc.), authentication and authorization - each one is an aspect of security that you may or may not care about and have different requirements for each.

For network traffic encryption if we're talking an HTTP based API - the almost-always-correct answer is stick to HTTPS - so the encryption problem is a solved one as long as you keep the server / client properly configured (enable peer verification, stick to secure and up-to-date TLS implementations and cyphers etc.). It is most likely already supported by your API client and server - just make sure the server doesn't accept any cleartext HTTP.

For authentication and authorization there are some common standards (like OAuth) but this really depends on your business logic needs.

Comment: I was into the idea that HTTP only works for web based system. I believe what I want for our system is network traffic security, as it is the time where the data is being transferred to the API (correct me if i'm wrong here). Oauth is also a nice idea, cant believe I forgot about it. thanks for this information. I will contact my API for further information and to get an idea on which direction I would choose.

Comment: HTTP is a protocol to transfer data over the network. It is used for the World Wide Web and also for APIs (REST, SOAP etc.). I'm not sure what do you mean by "Web based systems" - you mean Web sites? If so, HTTP is not only for that. If you plan to implement some data access or RPC-style API over the network unless you need something very specific, HTTP is probably the way to go.

Comment: Oh and of course, you can probably apply TLS on any TCP-based network socket. Even if you don't use HTTP - for encryption TLS is probably the common way to go

Comment: yes i meant web sites, thank you for that clarification though, i always assumed it was only meant for web sites. also thank you for this information's. i'll go and do some reading about them, and decide which one to use. but if you can suggest what you believe is the most secure way to transfer data, that would also be helpful :)

Comment: "The most secure"? - sorry, no such thing. It all depends on your requirements and the context. My advice would be not to reinvent any wheels, go with proven and common standards (i.e. HTTPS for encryption). Authentication and Authorization really depend on your business needs.

Comment: true it will all depend on what i need, is it possible to combine some other layers of security with HTTPS like TLS? thank you once again for this informations. I will wait for the feedback from the API, though if i want to encrypt the data sent trough them, then i guess https would be one way to approach this problem, i might add a few more just to be sure